# best methods to achieve Internationalization in node js application

Tags: node.js

We want to achieve internationalization in our node js application. we are trying with i18n but problem is if our application hosted in different nodes(example. 5 nodes)then we need to keep same local files in 5 nodes. Can you please suggest me better solutions?. Also please suggest us better ways to achieve internationalization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that having a copy of your i18n files should pose any problems because copying them should be part of your deployment scripts. In any case, I would suggest i18next, which is what I'm using for my current project. The client can obtain resources from a web server and these resources can be broken down by language and "namespace". So, you files could reside on a single host and be accessed by all of the other nodes. That's not counting all of the other really neat features of this library.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. i give a try now. thanks alot